# Passing jquery variable to ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my function

```
  $("body").on('click','.btn-info', function(e){
    var email = [];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
       email.push($(this).parent().siblings().eq(2).text());

    });
     alert(email);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://birdys.app/admin/sendpromocode',
        data: JSON.stringify(email),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {
        alert('data');
    }   

    function errorFunc() {
        alert('error');
    }
   /** $.get('http://birdys.app/admin/sendpromocode',email,function(data){
        alert(data);
    },'json');*/
});
```

I get the email value on checkbox clicked and pass that value to my ajax function but it doesnot worked for me how can i get this value inside ajax function..

Comment: why are you quoting url?  there is no need of `'`

Answer (score 0):

Stringify your data before use. You can call the below function inside your click listener like`getDetails(email)`.  Also see the consoled `error` for more info.

```
   function getDetails(data) {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://birdys.app/admin/sendpromocode',
            data: {emailList: data},
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {
            //success callback
        }

        function errorFunc(xhr, error) {
            console.log(error);
             console.log(xhr);
        }
    }
```

Also, here -> `$.get('url',email,function(data){` since url is a variable, dont need quotes

Comment: Thank you ninja I change it according to this but i get an error alert

Comment: what is the error message? Maybe you are not sending what your server needs.

Comment: Its really bad example of sending json data with GET. I would use POST instead

Comment: @Karthiga It is better to keep it as a separate function instead of writing it inside event listner.

Comment: when i console the error meesage it shows the parse error

Comment: @Karthiga that may be because you are not expecting a `json`.  remove ` dataType: "json",` from code

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142787/discussion-between-ninja-and-karthiga).